# Как кешировать аудио c#

Tags: c#, naudio

код приблизительно такой .....

```
using ( AudioFileReader audioFile = new AudioFileReader( filePath ) ) {
    using ( WaveOutEvent outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent( ) ) {
        outputDevice.Init( audioFile );
        outputDevice.Play( );

        while ( PlaybackState.Playing == outputDevice.PlaybackState ) {
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Либо вам сможет ответить только тот человек, который использует то же самое, что и вы, либо вам надо рассекретить свой код, и показать его в вопросе.

Comment: Весь код я скидывать не стал но аудио я воиспровожу так

Comment: А у вас там что-то секретное?) Библиотека с открытым исходным кодом... И код необходимо прилагать в теккстовом виде.

Comment: да с телефона не получилось поэтому отправлять так

Comment: Вставьте код текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы можете считать файл в `MemoryStream`, потом из него сколько угодно раз воспроизвести. Кстати `Thread.Sleep()` - эта штука вешает вам приложение.

Comment: да я знаю это я сейчас просто минимальный пример сделал